# how to unit test AOP?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, unity-container, aop

i'm using Unity to do AOP, could someone give me some idea how to unit test them?

Comment: Did you find a concrete way of doing this? I read the answer but it's not very clear?

Answer (score 1):

Does your "aspect" implementation is a class that implements `ICallHandler` (or very similar `IInterceptionBehavior` in Unity 2.0) and is already added to intercepted object's execution pipeline?

If so, you can test it separately quite ordinarily. What you test is `Invoke` method - call it with mock created for `IMethodInvocation`, set up to have your object's state before invoking the aspect and with `GetNextHandlerDelegate` to mock object set up to represent your intercepted object call.

You can then assert:

- on your delegate target if proper
  calls are made - i.e. test whether
  the aspect breks/doesn't break the
  execution properly, whether the call
  arguments were properly altered etc.
- on `Invoke`'s result (`IMethodReturn`
  object) - i.e. test whether the
  return result was properly altered,
  whether the exception was thrown etc.